# joining data frames and substitutung rows

Tags: r, join

I have a table like this: data1

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  d  t
2  b  d  w
3  c  e  t
4  a  d  t
5  b  f  w
6  c  g  t
7  a  h  w
8  b  k  w
9  c  e  w
```

and data2:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  d  w
2  b  f  t
3  c  e  t
```

Now I would like to substitute V3 from data1 with V3 from data2, for all rows that are identical in V1 and V2. So that I get a table like this:

```
   V1 V2 V3
1  a  d  w
2  b  d  w
3  c  e  t
4  a  d  t
5  b  f  t
6  c  g  t
7  a  h  w
8  b  k  w
9  c  e  t
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient answer, and you need to be careful if extending to larger data frames.  Since V3 exists in both data1 and data2 and we're not using it to join, the join will automatically attach a suffix to distinguish them.  In this example it's very straightforward but make sure you're aware of how it works if using for more complicated situations.

```
library(tidyverse)
data1 <- data_frame(V1=rep(c('a','b','c'),3),
                    V2=c('d','d','e','d','f','g','h','k','e'),
                    V3=c('t','w','t','t','w','t','w','w','w'))

data2 <- data_frame(V1=c('a','b','c'),
                    V2=c('d','f','e'),
                    V3=c('w','t','t'))

left_join(data1,data2,by=c('V1','V2')) %>%
  mutate(V3=coalesce(V3.y,V3.x)) %>%
  select(-V3.x,-V3.y)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     d     w    
2 b     d     w    
3 c     e     t    
4 a     d     w    
5 b     f     t    
6 c     g     t    
7 a     h     w    
8 b     k     w    
9 c     e     t
```

Comment: @NinaW. No problem.  If you're happy with my answer and/or any of the other answers you can mark it as the answer that way people know you've chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[data2, V3 := i.V3, on = .(V1, V2)]
data1
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  a  d  w
#2:  b  d  w
#3:  c  e  t
#4:  a  d  w
#5:  b  f  t
#6:  c  g  t
#7:  a  h  w
#8:  b  k  w
#9:  c  e  t
```

#### data

```
data1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", 
"c"), V2 = c("d", "d", "e", "d", "f", "g", "h", "k", "e"), V3 = c("t", 
"w", "t", "t", "w", "t", "w", "w", "w")), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")

data2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "b", "c"), V2 = c("d", "f", "e"), 
V3 = c("w", "t", "t")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

Your dataframes

```
data1<-data.frame(V1=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
V2=c("d","d","e","d","f","g","h","k","e"),
V3=c("t","w","t","t","w","t","w","w","w"))

data2<-data.frame(V1=c("a","b","c"),
                  V2=c("d","f","e"),
                  V3=c("w","t","t"))
```

join them using columns `V1` and `V2`

```
library("dplyr")
data3<-left_join(data1,data2,by=c("V1","V2"))
data3
  V1 V2 V3.x V3.y
1  a  d    t    w
2  b  d    w <NA>
3  c  e    t    t
4  a  d    t    w
5  b  f    w    t
6  c  g    t <NA>
7  a  h    w <NA>
8  b  k    w <NA>
9  c  e    w    t
```

Substitution of appropriate values

```
data3[!is.na(data3[,4]),3]<-data3[!is.na(data3[,4]),4]
```

Your output

```
data3[,-4]
  V1 V2 V3.x
1  a  d    w
2  b  d    w
3  c  e    t
4  a  d    w
5  b  f    t
6  c  g    t
7  a  h    w
8  b  k    w
9  c  e    t
```

Comment: moved the solution to dplyr, I'm not a purist of  base R code as you can see